# R dashboard, googlevis options

Tags: r, googlevis

here is my Q:
I am using googlevis (gvisTreeMap) function to illustrate a data frame. it is automatically put the labels on each block, but I want to have the numbers too. 
here is my simplified code:

```
 col1 <- c(1,2,3,5,8)
    col2 <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
    fdata <- data.frame(col1,col2)

    total <- data.frame(col1=sum(fdata$col1), col2="Market Share")

    fdata1 <- rbind(total, fdata)
    fdata1$parent="Market Share"
    ## Set parent variable to NA at root level
    fdata1$parent[fdata1$col2=="Market Share"] <- NA
    fdata1$col1.log=log(fdata1$col1)


    aa <- gvisTreeMap(fdata1, "col2", "parent",
                              "col1", "col1.log",
                   options=list(width=600, height=500,
                                  fontSize=16,
                                  minColor='#EDF8FB',
                                  midColor='#66C2A4',
                                  maxColor='#006D2C',
                                  headerHeight=20,
                                  fontColor='black',
                                  showScale=TRUE, lable="$$"))



    plot(aa)
```

to make it more clear, after I run the code I have five blocks with letters on it, but I want both letters and numbers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed your definition of `col2` to append the size to each entry (with the exception of the root node):

```
fdata1$col2=paste0(fdata1$col2, " - ", fdata1$col1)
fdata$col2[1] <- "Market Share"
```

[image]